# Reduced cell in grouped UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am adding one more section to the existing `tableView` and getting this:

[image]

my new cell is reduced by height. Appropriate methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return cells[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([headers[section] isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
        return [headers[section] frame].size.height;

    return 10.0f;
}

- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([headers[section] isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
        return headers[section];

    return nil;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = cells[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];

    if (cell == clientXibCell) return 100.0f;
    if (cell == agencyXibCell) return 145.0f;
    return 46.0f;
}
```

I can't understand what I need to do to fix this. Any ideas where the source of issue can be?

**Update**
I am now sure that predefining custom cell visual interface making this trouble.

```
supervisorCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:nil];
    bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:supervisorCell.backgroundView.frame];
    [bgView setImage:stretchableImageByHorizontal([UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bgd_bottom"])];
    [supervisorCell setBackgroundView:bgView]; 
    bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:supervisorCell.backgroundView.frame];
    [bgView setImage:stretchableImageByHorizontal([UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bgd_bottom_active"])];
    [supervisorCell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgView];
```

When I am uncommenting everything except first statement of creating the cell, everything works fine except custom appearance of cell. What do I need to change in this simple code to fix this?

Comment: try change `bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:supervisorCell.backgroundView.frame];`  by `bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:supervisorCell.contentView.frame];`

Comment: Thank you again, @Lucas! Unfortunately this not helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of your cells are controlled by the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. Taking a look on your code, it seems that this method is always returning `46`.

Your two `ifs` are comparing pointers, i. e., instancies of your cells. It means that of all your cells, one will have the height `100`, one `145` and all others `46.f`.

I think what are you trying to accomplish is set this height for all cells of the same kind, so you should change your `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method, like below:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ( [cell isKindOfClass:[YourCustomCell1 class]] ) return 100.0f;
    if ( [cell isKindOfClass:[YourCustomCell2 class]] ) return 145.0f;
    return 46.0f;
}
```

Ps1: Change `YourCustomCell` class for your own classes. If you don't have subclasses, try to set tags or something like that to differentiate them.

Ps2: always use tableview's method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to get the reference of the cell by the indexPath.

Comment: Thanks, @Lucas! That whas first what I tried. Please see updated post

Comment: you was close to the idea, but the answer was much more simple. I imported wrong call background image file with this reduced top. But your answer was useful, thanks! So, accepted